# bootstrap-table: how to load data from mysql database with ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bootstrap-table

Please correct my code because I don't know how to correctly fill the bootstrap-table with the data form mysql database. I guess that the problem is the incompatible format of sending data with required format of bootstrap-table. As you see below, I tried both ways to load, but neither one works and I want to you use post method.

**html code:**

```
<table id="stable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">id</th>
      <th data-field="name">name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**php code:**

```
if (!empty($_POST["tab"])) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM tab";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $values = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $values[] =  $row["id"].",".$row["name"];
    }
    echo json_encode($values);
}
```

**js code:**

```
var t = [
      {  "id": "1",
       "name": "john"
      },
      { "id": "2",
        "name": "ted"
      }
    ];
var tab = "stat";
$.post( 
    "pfile.php",
    { tab },
    function(data) {
        //$('#stable').bootstrapTable('load', data);
        $('#stable').bootstrapTable({
            data: data  //t
        });
    },
    "json"
);
```

If I assign `data: t` then it works correctly. If I use `data: data` then I get this:
[image]

`alert(t)` gives me `[object Object],[object Object]` so I should create and pass somehow the object array from php file.

Comment: So what is the format you need and what do you have now? I would guess your manually concatenated comma-separated string is the problem.

Comment: @soonic include the required data in the question. Also, add a more specific description about what is a happening that is undesirable. 'neither one works' is not a sufficient explanation to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post, hopefully it's more clear now. I don't know how to write my php code correctly so it would send the array like the `t` variable show.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working with mysql database. I couldn't find an answer on the internet as I needed (I've seen a few questions about the same) so I'm posting here, maybe someone will be in the similar situation. Now the fix looks so simple, that I wounder why nobody hadn't answer yet. Generally, I needed to change only this line:  `$values[] =  $row;`

Referring to my post and putting all together:

php code:

```
if (!empty($_POST["tab"])) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM tab";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $values = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $values[] =  $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($values);
}
```

**js code:**

```
var tab = "stat";
$.post( 
    "pfile.php",
    { tab },
    function(data) {
        $('#stable').bootstrapTable({
            data: data 
        });
    },
    "json"
);
```